# C++ Behavior of virtual functions in parent member function

Tags: c++, virtual

I have a doubt regarding the behavior of virtual function when used within the parent member function.

Ex

```
class A {
private:
   vars;
   virtual fn_v() {.....}
public:
   fn_A() {
     fn_v();
     ....
   }

class B : public A {
   ....
public:
   fn_v() {.....}
```

When I call `fn_A()` from an object of B which implementation of virtual function will be called?

Comment: It depends. Do call the function through a pointer or reference to the base `A` class? Is this pointer or reference really a pointer or reference to an instance of the `B` class? Then the `B::fn_v` function should be called.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: It is a generic object of class `B`.

Comment: `B::fn_v` will be called (assuming you are not in B's constructor or destructor)

Comment: Have you tried to actually do it?

Comment: Your question is answered by simply trying it.

Answer (score 0):

> When I call fn_A() from an object of B which implementation of virtual function will be called?

The one in `B`, of course. That's what virtual functions mean. If the object on which the method is called is of a class which overrides the virtual method, the override will be called. This is rather basic.

Comment: @PaulStelian I don't know what exactly you mean by 'through indirect calls', but it works whenever the object the method is called on is of a class which overrides the virtual method. I can't put it any plainer than that.